# draw empty mx:grid flex programmatically

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I want to draw 2*2 mx:Grid and put a button on any one of these cells which will be calculated dynamically. So I want to create an empty 2*2 grid, and replace any one cell with the button.

```
-----------------
|        |       |
------------------
|        |  btn  |
------------------
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create grid and keep references to the cells (instances of `GridItem`). Consider following code as a part of some class.

```
private var cells:Array = [];

private function addGrid(parent:DisplayObjectContainer):void {
    var grid:Grid = new Grid();
    var row1:GridRow = new GridRow();
    grid.addChild(row1);
    var cell11:GridItem = new GridItem();
    row1.addChild(cell11);
    var cell12:GridItem = new GridItem();
    row1.addChild(cell12);
    cells.push(new Array(cell11, cell12));
    var row2:GridRow = new GridRow();
    grid.addChild(row2);
    cell21 = new GridItem();
    row2.addChild(cell21);
    var cell22:GridItem = new GridItem();
    row2.addChild(cell22);
    cells.push(new Array(cell21, cell22));
    parent.addChild(grid);
}
```

`cells` is two-dimensional array, which can be used to access the cells you need to change. You can use `Vector` class instead of `Array`. I've used `Array` only because of shorter code.

Comment: Thanks Petr.. in the future I will need to initialize larger grid so is it possible to initialize empty grid using double for loops?

Comment: @asokBuzz I'm afraid I don't understand what do you mean by double for loops.

Comment: I want to draw grid inside loop, so that I don't have to make every row and columns each time

Comment: @asokBuzz It is definitely possible. Array makes it very easy. If you're interested, I can amend the answer to show you how to do it.

Comment: thanks, I did that. Now I have already created 2*2 grid and placed button on last cell, now how can I replace that button with another?

Comment: @asokBuzz Given that button is only child of the cell you can use `cell.removeChildAt(0)` and then add a new button via `cell.addChild(newButton)`.